# What is the best way substracting weeks from a given date with moment.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs

What is the best way to substract weeks from a given date with moment.js?

Let's say I am getting a date from the user with dd-mm-yyyy format. I would like to display date - 10weeks.

For example, let's say the user input is: 18042013

The result should be: 18042013 - 10weeks

I am playing with momentjs but cannot figure out how to achieve this. Any idea?

Comment: In vanilla JavaScript: `var d = new Date(2013,3,18); d.setDate(-7*w);`

Comment: `moment().subtract("weeks", 10)`

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
var week = moment().subtract('week', 10);
alert(week);
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bWhc5/14/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without need of any libraries...

```
var MS_PER_MINUTE = 60000;
var MS_PER_HOUR = MS_PER_MINUTE*60;
var MS_PER_DAY = MS_PER_HOUR*24;
var MS_PER_WEEK = MS_PER_DAY*7;

var _DATE_ = new Date()-MS_PER_WEEK*NUM_WEEKS;
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mgleeson/njesr5dp/)**